# Как установить признак фокуса RadioButton

Tags: c#, avalonia

При движении по контролам RadioButton и CheckBox клавишей TAB момент получения контролом фокуса визуально заметен а программный фокус не заметен вообще . Как сделать чтобы программный .Focus() визуально выделял бы контрол как клавишей TAB .

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ответ я нашел как и ожидалось в стилях <Style Selector="RadioButton:focus"> я не видел этого ни в одном примере . Но мою проблему это не решило . Теперь вопрос такой : как заменить клавишу TAB клавишей ENTER ?

Comment: Вот это решает проблему таба             InitializeComponent();
            this.AddHandler<KeyEventArgs>(KeyDownEvent, OnKeyDown, RoutingStrategies.Tunnel, true);